# CJSON length of parsed JSON

Tags: c, cjson

I tried out cJSON and discovered that even if I give an correct JSON followed by an incorrect JSON, it takes the entire content into its `parse_buffer` struct (in `cJSON.c`) and parses only the correct JSON. I can easily get the length of the total parsed content by doing something like:
`buffer.length` in `cJSON.c` after the parsing is completed.

If I have a file which contains something like:

```
{
    "text": "HelloWorld!!"
}
{
    "text" : "incompletejson"
```

the cJSON puts the entire contents into its buffer and parses only the valid part.

If in my program I write:

```
//open file and read contents in buffer
/* Parse buffer into cJSON structure */
cJSON *root = cJSON_Parse(buffer);
char *text = cJSON_GetObjectItem(root, "text")->valuestring;
printf("text: %s\n", text);
```

it prints out `HelloWorld!!`.

Is there a way to get the length of just the parsed content i.e., the correct JSON that has been parsed? Is this at all possible in cJSON?

Comment: You want to use `cJSON_ParseWithOpts` instead of `cJSON_Parse`. Docs for `cJSON_Parse` say "*If an error occurs a pointer to the position of the error in the input string can be accessed using `cJSON_GetErrorPtr`. Note though that this can produce race conditions in multithreading scenarios, in that case it is better to use `cJSON_ParseWithOpts` with `return_parse_end`. By default, characters in the input string that follow the parsed JSON will not be considered as an error.*"

Comment: @ikegami, could you provide an example of `cJSON_ParseWithOpts` with the length of parsed JSON?

Comment: `*return_parse_end - value` gives the offset at which it stopped parsing. Probably have to set the last parameter to `1`.

Comment: @ikegami, what I meant was how could I access the values of `cJSON_GetErrorPtr` and `return_parse_end`. I have set the last parameter in `cJSON_ParseWithOpts` to 1 so that now invalid JSONs are throwing an error. But I not able to figure out how I can access the value where the valid JSON ended.

Comment: For example if I try and execute `printf("cjSON parse buffer: %s\n", cJSON_GetErrorPtr());` it gives me a Memory Access Error.

Comment: Re "*I not able to figure out how I can access the value where the valid JSON ended.*", `*return_parse_end - value` gives the offset at which it stopped parsing. (Those are names of `ParseWithOpts` parameters.)